# Access particular row of p:datatable in Backing Bean on click of h:CommandLink without binding attribute

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

Please find my code below for p:datatable having h:commandlink as one of its column:

```
   <p:dataTable id="listTable" value="#{listBean.lazyDatalist}"
                         var="list" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="top" rows="10"
                         rowIndexVar="rowIndex" 
                        rowStyleClass="#{(rowIndex mod 2) eq 0 ? 'rowStyleOdd' : 'rowStyleEven'}" 
                        lazy="true">
                        <p:ajax event="page" listener="#{listBean.searchLazyData}"/>
                        <p:column style="width:3%;" headerText="#{msg['userlist.dt.srNo']}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{list.orderCount}"></h:outputText>
                        </p:column>                 
                        <p:column  style="width:7%;"
                            headerText="#{msg['userlist.dt.EmployeeID']}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{list.employeeID}"/>  
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column  style="width:12%;"
                            headerText="#{msg['userlist.dt.Name']}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{list.employeeName}"></h:outputText>  
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="#{msg['userlist.dt.actionReq']}">
                                <h:commandLink value="#{list.actionRequired}" action="#{listBean.getDetails}" styleClass="linkStyle"></h:commandLink>                       
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
```

I want to access the datatable row in Backing Bean ListBean for which h:commandLink is clicked using action="#{listBean.getDetails}" without using datatable binding attribute.

My Backingbean is session scoped and we are using jsf 2.1.7 Mojarra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But MOST of all, Take a look at the first selection example in the PrimeFaces showcase http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml

Comment: And please search for duplicates

Comment: Thanks :) But I want to use commandLink specifically and in primefaces all datatable selection features have commandButton. please help.

Comment: May I suggest to take a step back and learn some of the basics of jsf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688755/hcommandbutton-vs-hcommandlink

Answer (score 0):

Pass the selected row as parameter to your method such as

```
<h:commandLink value="#{list.actionRequired}" action="#{listBean.getDetails(list)}" styleClass="linkStyle"></h:commandLink>
```

and change `getDetails` to accept a parameter of element type of `listBean.lazyDatalist`

Comment: I tried the same but not able to pass parameter in action attribute.

Comment: "not able to pass" - have you ever passed a parameter to a method called by JSF? If not, you better learn that first.

Answer (score 0):

`var` contains the object which is used to fill each row. You can just pass it in your action like `#{listBean.getDetails(list)}`. Don´t forget to add this parameter to your bean method.

By the way: `list` is very misleading. You should better name it `element` or with it´s concrete entity name, maybe `employee`. Your team will be grateful.

Comment: Not able to pass parameter in action attribute. getting error in eclipse as "Syntax error in EL". Please help.